# this.state.todolist.push() in reactjs returns a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use `this.state.todolist.push()` in reactjs, it returns a number ？
but replacing push with concat returns a correct value.

```
var ToDosBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
            taskList:[]
        }
    },
    addCallback:function(e,value){
        var tasks = this.state.taskList.push({taskName:value,author:'test',time:'10:15'});
        //console.log(tasks);
        this.setState({taskList:tasks});
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="todos-box">
                <InputBox ref="inputBox" callback={this.addCallback} />
                <h3>Todo List</h3>
                <ToDosList items={this.state.taskList} />
            </div>
            )
    }
})
```

Comment: select the code and click ctrl+k to format it correctly

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't use `this.state.todolist` anywhere. Are you talking about `this.state.taskList`? Have you looked at the documentation for `.push()` to see what it is supposed to return?

Comment: Sorry .It is my fault, and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> returns the new length property of the object upon which the method
>   was called.

you don't need variable `tasks`, you can pass to `setState` method `this.state.taskList`, like this

```
addCallback: function (e, value) {
    this.state.taskList.push({
        taskName: value, author: 'test', time: '10:15'
    });

    this.setState({taskList: this.state.taskList});
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/10195/)